# Prevent ajax from re-downloading js files

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am using ajax for displaying content on my website content area. On certain content page may contains slideshow or forms. Therefore, the ajax page may contain some js script files. But, every-time when I revisit page with the js script files, it reload the js files from the server by adding `?_={timestamp}` at the back of the script url.

For example:

1. I access an ajax page with form plugin.
2. Then, I access to other normal ajax page.
3. After that, I access other ajax page with form plugin again. When accessing, the ajax will retrieve the form plugin from the server again with something like this `http://localhost/mywebs/js/jquery.form.min.js?_=1395904522973`

How can I cache or prevent the ajax from re-downloading the js script file from the server?

Thank you.

Comment: why you use a timestamp? maybe its better to set a version number `?v=1.337`

Comment: I didn't use timestamp. It is automatically added to the end of url by ajax. So, is there anyway to prevent it?

Comment: So i think time stamp is the issue every time your ajax will add a new time

Comment: @DholakiyaAnkit Yeah, so how can I prevent it from adding time stamp?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.load` to only load part of page (e.g. only `<div id='content'>` block.

Answer (score 0):

I presume you are downloading and and writing inserting that in your DOM with some script tag.
Now when you write that put a id in the script tag like below.

```
<script id="myJsFileID">
//the js content
</script>
```

and each time when u fire the ajax check the inner content is blank or the script element with that tag at all present and thus a take a decision to fire the ajax 2nd time.